# Why can't I change the color of my UITableViewCell's text?

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch

I use the following code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The background color changes fine, but the text stays black!

**What am I doing wrong?** Is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.  I believe your best option would be to change the color inside your storyboard to avoid calling the wrong functions.  There is also a possibility (and I'm sorry I can't comment on posts at my rep) that you might have put in the wrong Cell Identifier.

**EDIT**
Correct answer was that if you're using a custom NIB for the cell, make sure you reference its UILabel and not the default one.

Comment: This screen is completely programmatic; it's not created with a XIB/NIB/storyboard. Every other change, including background color, works fine. The fact that they rep-block commenting is stupid, and I wish I could let you.

Comment: That's true :).  Anyway, I just tried changing the color in the way that you did, and I see that it apparently is not changing anything.  Could you show me your whole cellForRowAtIndexPath() method?  Thanks

Comment: Actually, that spurred me to look deeper! I discovered that our custom cells all use the same NIB, and that NIB has its own custom UILabel. I referenced that to change the color and it worked. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll be glad to if you reference the actual solution in it! Simply say something like "If you're using a custom NIB for the cell, make sure you reference its UILabel and not the default one."